# How to typesafe check equality of booleans?

Tags: java, comparator

```
public class ComplexObject {
    private boolean isA, isB;
}

//custom comparator
public boolean checkComplexObject(ComplexObject o1, ComplexObject o2) {
   return o1.getIsA() == o2.getIsB();
}
```

Now when I change the data type in `ComplexObject` from `boolean` to `String` for example, the comparator will not break, nor will I notice that in future I would compare Strings instead of booleans and thus get different results.

Question: how could I compare the boolean properties typesafe, so that I get compilation error when I change the datatype of the fields?

Comment: Why can't You just use .equals method, so it would work, for string, or whatever type You would utilise?

Comment: `boolean b1 =  o1.getIsA()` would pretty much set that in stone.

Comment: @maslan because boolean does not support the .equals() method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik so, why not just use a wrapper Boolean?

Comment: @maslan a wrapper would be a unused boxing + unboxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very simple thing you can do is put in a redundant cast:

```
return (boolean)o1.getIsA() == (boolean)o2.getIsB();
```

You can also define a method that only accepts `boolean`:

```
static boolean booleanEquals(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Then call `booleanEquals` instead of using `==`.

---

As a side note, this programming seems a bit overly defensive to me.

Comment: Overly defensive not in my case, as I just stumbled open exactly this issue and try to workaround this unbreakable in future.

Comment: *"Overly defensive not in my case"* Well, sure. I'm not judging, I just felt the need to point it out if there wasn't a reason behind it.

Comment: Just one cast of the two would do it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's true. Personally I usually cast both sides since I think it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do, but all of them will make your code less readable, and therefore I would advise against them.

For example :

```
return o1.getIsA() ^ o2.getIsB() == false;
```

or

```
return (o1.getIsA() && o2.getIsB()) ||  (!o1.getIsA() && !o2.getIsB());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XOR for that:

```
return o1.getIsA() ^ o2.getIsB();
```

Answer (score 0):

The better question is, **why would you do that?**

If you refactor (well, change heavily) your attributes from `boolean` to `String` you should always check the affected code. If you want code workarounds for a common practice (double checking), you're may introduce overly complicated code in your whole application.

If you're aware of that problem, why dont you put a comment directly on your affected class attributes, that it may be compared by ==. If you want or another dev wants to change it's type later on, they will be warned.

Comment: Most of the reasons strong static typing exists are defensive.

Comment: @Radiodef Well, most of the solutions here are rather unreadable, but your casting variant seems elegant with no big overhead to me.